# How to sendmail via php with dynamic url

Tags: php, onclick, echo, sendmail

I have a big problem! I need to track what the users are doing on my site. As a way to resolve it I crated a sendmail function in order to send me an email every time a user clicks on a button. The code is this:

```
<div class="buy">
<a onclick="target='_blank'" href="<?php echo $this->product['from'];?>">

<?php
// The message
$message = "A new buy";
$link = "<?php echo $this->product['from'];?>";

// Send
mail('xxx@mail.com', '@buy PRODUCT', $message, $link);
?> 

<img src="http://xxx.com/data/images/xxx.jpg" alt="Comprar"       />                            
</a>
</div>
```

The message I receive is

```
"A new buy

**<?php echo $this->product['from'];?>**"
```

And it should look like:

"A new buy

**http://www.xxxx.com**"

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: $link = $this->product['from'];

Comment: a bot hitting your site could end up sending you a lot of mail, i would recommend logging to a db instead. - true story - i did this with a 404 page (1 email per hit), one night i got 40k emails from a rouge crawling bot - had to call the isp to get the mail box purged.

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying! I tried adding that line and didn't worked, now shows nothing! Anyhting more I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then try this:

```
$message = "A new buy ".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;//add two new lines for plaintext message
$message .= $this->product['from']; //add link to the end of message

// Send
mail('xxx@mail.com', '@buy PRODUCT', $message); //no need for fourth parameter
```

Read further:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

And for easy e-mailing use phpmailer:

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$link = "<?php echo $this->product['from'];?>";
```

use

```
$link = $this->product['from'];
```

Comment: Hi Alvar, thanks for replying! I changed to the code u posted and now is showing this:

Comment: Hi Alvar, thanks for replying! I changed to the code u posted and now is showing only the "A new buy" part and nothing more